# Unlink/cleanup unix socket only if it's still owned by process

Tags: c, linux, unix-socket

First time working with Unix domain sockets, now I'm trying to implement the cleanup part.

It already seemed a bit ugly that the general recommendation when creating your listening socket is to first try to unlink the desired socket path and then call bind. While you probably should make sure that your process is only running once, I'm trying to prepare for the situation where for some reason it will be launched twice. For the service itself it doesn't matter too much: The first instance's socket is unlinked by the second instance, so it's unreachable, wastes some RAM, but doesn't do any harm. But how would I implement cleanup that works in this situation? Simply doing

```
close(sockFd);
unlink(sockPath);
```

would lead to the situation that if the first process exits while the second is still running, it would actually delete the second process' socket from the file system. Boom, no service.

I can only think of a few ugly hacks that wouldn't be atomic so could still mess things up, so I'm hoping there is a better paradigm to prevent ending up in this situation. Something like funlink(sockFd) would have been nice. Otherwise I'd have to resort to never cleaning up the socket, which isn't the end of the world, but feels quite messy to me.

Abstract domain sockets looked quite promising (even though it would tie me to Linux for now), but unfortunatly they don't seem to support permissions, which is a requirement in my case.

Comment: Here's what I normally do to avoid 2 processes trying to listen on the same unix domain socket. The first thing I do is attempt to connect to the socket. If the connection works, there's already a listener running, I bail out. Otherwise I'll allow the process to continue and listen on the socket. Cleanup should be easy because you are sure you have only 1 listener.

Comment: The correct approach though is to attempt to bind to the socket and you will get `EADDRINUSE` if the socket is already in use. Now you know another process is already listening on it, you can bail out.

Comment: @alvits I think you get the <code>EADDRINUSE</code> even if the first process exited and there's just the lingering socket in the file system left, so that's no better than unconditinally removing the socket at startup, but the connect before bind might be an option; I'll try around a bit...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate lock file that your application locks with `flock(..., LOCK_EX)` before doing anything with the socket. As long as all application instances agree on what lock file to use you are safe, and `flock()` is atomic. Cleanup is no issue with `flock()` as the lock is released when the process dies.